# Jquery revert textboxes back to their original values

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, default-value

I have a popup form with 4 textboxes, all of which have default values when the page loads.

Here's the scenario... The user has filled in the form with their details but decides not to submit the form and closes the popup. I want the values of the textboxes to revert to their default values when the user close the popup.

Here's my code so far.

```
$(".close").click( function() {
    $(".popup").find("input").val("Default value of textbox");
});
```

Rather than inserting "Default value of textbox" as the value, I want it to be the actual default value.

Comment: isn't this what <input type='reset' /> is for?

Comment: you could use the form inputs "defaultValue" property ? http://www.appnovation.com/blog/quick-tip-using-javascript%E2%80%99s-defaultvalue-form-elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put the default values in a 'data attribute' on the elements themselves...I'll create a fiddle to show this... [As seen in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alr3/Z3A4h/1/)

I should also note that you can put the data attribute on the elements from the server...I'm just showing how you could do it all from the client...

Comment: Yes and no...html is nothing but xml right, and data attributes can be just attributes to the html elements...which is what I am suggesting...

Comment: No problem!  ...when you get a chance, and if this is the best answer, don't forget to 'accept' the answer...

Comment: Is it possible to dispense with getting the values and just revert to defaultValue?         $('input').each(function (curIdx, curO) {
            $(curO).val($(curO).prop("defaultValue"));
        });

Answer (score 1):

```
                // First store all the default values
                var def_vals = [];

                jQuery('#popup input[type="text"]').each(

                    function () {

                        def_vals[jQuery(this).attr('name')] = jQuery(this).val();

                    }
                );

                alert(def_vals['test']);

            // Restore defaults on close



            jQuery('#popup .closeButton').click( function () {

                jQuery('#popup input[type=text]').each(

                    function() {

                        jQuery(this).val(def_vals[jQuery(this).attr('name')]);

                    }

                );

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

By way of closure

```
// add to the place that opens the popup
$(".popup input").one(function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   var that = this;
   $(".close").one(function(){
      $(that).val(value);
   });
});
```